# C# rethrow exception without try-catch block

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

## Rethrow Exception without try-catch block

Is there any option in **C#** how to rethrow an Exception without using a `try..catch` block?

Example from **Java**:

```
public static void SomeMethod()   throws FileNotFoundException{
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("java.pdf");
}
```

Comment: You may want to specify it in documentation: `/// <exception cref="System.IO.FileNotFoundException">Thrown when java.pdf not found</exception>`

Comment: Just a side-note: you shouldn't `rethrow` an exception inside a `try`/`catch` - it changes the stack trace - just let it bubble up by default - **unless you can meaningfully handle the exception.**

Comment: @DmitryBychenko That’s exactly what I wanted to know. So i can do nothing and just write to documentation what could be thrown by that method? I mean is It a good practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just don't do anything at all. If there's no try-catch block, your exception will bubble up the call stack until it finds one.

Note that there are no checked exceptions in C#, so it's the default implicit behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike **Java** in **C#** we don't have to specify exceptions which can be thrown in the method:

```
    public static void SomeMethod() {
      FileReader reader = new FileReader("java.pdf");
    }
```

However, it's a *good practice* to let developer / user know which exceptions can be thrown. You can specify them with a help of documenting comments, see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/exception

for details:

```
/// <summary>
/// Performs Some Method
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="System.IO.FileNotFoundException">Thrown when java.pdf not found</exception>
public static void SomeMethod() {
  FileReader reader = new FileReader("java.pdf");
}
```